# Once per day, it has to send an email automatically if one my numbers in a array is <1

Tags: vba, excel

In one day, many employees are opening my VBA Program.

I have one excel sheet with some numbers inside, on the top I have email (B1=CEO@group.com....C1=COO@group.com..), and in the column A I have numbers (234,323,444...).

What I need is:

When the first employee is opening the program in the day, the program has to send message if the number is < 1 (It can send more than one message if there is more value less than 1)

Per example with C5=0 Then send a message to the COO@group with the number of column A (444) in the body message.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is somewhere in your sheet (hidden). Record the day(date, either?) and a count of how many times its been opened.

If the day changes reset the clock and use that a place to build your logic and code for if i<1

If the times opened is greater than 1 do not do the check for if your number<1